# Как сделать деление pictureBox по форме в C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, picturebox

У меня есть форма и бокс, в боксе вставлена гифка. Прописаное движение хаотичное бокса по форме. Нужно, чтобы бокс спустя n-ое кол-во секунд делился на 2, далее те 2 на 4 и так далее. Как осуществить это деление?

Comment: Используй таймер, в обработчике срабатывания таймера пробегайся по коллекции своих боксов и для каждого создавай новый бокс. Новые созданные боксы сохраняй в отдельную коллекцию. После того как цикл закончится объедени две коллекции боксов (добавь новые боксы в коллекцию к старым).

Comment: мне кажется вам проще будет все боксы засовывать в `panel`... тогда вам не нужна будет коллекция и вы сможете управлять динамическими боксами (по кол-ву и величине) в статическом (панели)...конечно ж если она не поменяет своего размера.